# Risk of code injection with explode() and count()?

Tags: php, code-injection

I'm working with a website which currently stores product ID lists in a **string** within the URL.

Looks like this: `localhost/product-list?compare=7011,7012,7013`

This list gets split up using `explode()` and `count()`ed to show the amount of products on the page.

Should I be worried about people inserting their own values in the URL, is there any risk of code injection using `explode()` and `count()`?

Comment: No because `count` returns an integer.  If displaying strings look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Not really, as neither `explode` or `count` have the ability to actually modify anything in your PHP.

Comment: No need to worry, but I you really want to sanitize the data in the request, you can use `filter_var` to ensure parameters are integers.

Comment: But no need for `explode` just `echo substr_count($_GET['compare'], ',') + 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it really depends upon how they are being used inside your code. For example, if you are querying these IDs in your database. It should be fine if you are using parameterized queries to achieve this. However, in order to make sure that weird inputs don't roam around in your code, you could validate using a simple [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for digits(IDs) and commas.

```
<?php

$compare = '7011,7012,7013';// or from $_GET

var_dump(preg_match('/^(\d+,?)+$/',$compare));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/WjeDe